# Bootstrap Menu not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is my first attempt to build a bootstrap website. I can't figure out why my menu does not work. The following buttons are linking to URL's (Home, About Contact) which I can get to when I add the URL's to the body of the page but not for the menu.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <META name="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>">
  <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.tdtandassociates.co.za/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://www.tdtandassociates.co.za/js/main.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body id="myPage" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse-1" data-offset="60">
  <!-- Nav Bar Container -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.tdtandassociates.co.za">HOME</a>
    </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">SERVICES <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Interim Management</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Permanent Placements</a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Senior & Specialists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Targeted Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Market Mapping</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Talent Pipelining</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="active"><a href="http://www.tdtandassociates.co.za/#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.tdtandassociates.co.za/#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your href="#" means it will only link back to the page where you are on. Try to change those into an actual html page (i.e. Senior Specialist goes to specialist.html).

Comment: Yep I do know that. My question does highlight that the Home, About and Contact menu options are using actual URL's which are not redirecting when clicked.

Comment: can you post the actual code which links those menu items to the page?

Comment: It is posted above no?     <li class="active"><a href="http://www.tdtandassociates.co.za/#about">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.tdtandassociates.co.za/#contact">CONTACT</a></li>

Comment: When the page is rendered, hover your mouse over the menu. What do you see on the browser's status bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what's causing your issue.

In your JS file (main.js), there's a line of code which prevents the link to redirect (See where the comment **Prevent default anchor click behavior** is located):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links in navbar + footer link
  $(".navbar a, footer a[href='#myPage']").on('click', function(event) {

  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (900) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 900, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
    });
  });
})
```

Try to comment that code out and see whether it navigates to the link now.

Answer (score -3):

use [this](http://www.layoutit.com/build)

drag a Navbar

see the source created

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                        </div> 
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider">
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice example of a top menu to work off but even after implementing and using proper URLs in each of the menu links, I am still getting the same result. It does not redirect to the URL in the <a href=""> tag.